# Grey Font Color Printing

Tags: html, printing, fonts, colors, cross-browser

Is there any way to ensure that my grey font colors do not turn black?

Firefox and Chrome seem to do this in order to prevent white text on black background from turning into white on white. I do not have a background color (except white), so this browser-level conversion is not useful, it only helps in preventing grey colors for no reason.

Is there a way to turn this off? Or should I just stick with techniques like opacity, browser detection, and coloring my grays...

Comment: are you using a print stylesheet?

Comment: I always thought black was forced because blank ink prints much faster and is cheaper than printing grey, because that requires the use of colour ink.

Comment: opacity sounds like a great technique - if all else fails, I would resort to that or PDFs.

Comment: @Radagaisus, I use a separate style sheet for printing if that is what you mean. (units in `in`,`pt`,`em`,`%`) For non-print-views I use a style sheet that sets background color, includes formatting for buttons, interactive components, etc. (units in `px`,`em`,`%`)

Comment: @thirtydot, That may be! But customer certainly does not care if it takes slightly more ink. They specifically want this text to be faded as it is rarely of any use to anyone.

Comment: @Pekka, It is great when it works! Not so good when Chrome entirely hides the faded text. I do my best with the techniques listed, but customer would not appreciate it if I made them download a PDF every time they wanted to print.

Comment: @George fair enough - but remember that you can embed PDFs inline using an `iframe`, with a "print" button and everything. (Just in case you need to come back to this)

Comment: The reason for software to convert grey text into black is that black laser printers need to raster grey. Raster pattern results (especially in low resolution printers) lead to fuzzy text appearance. When printing full black, there is no need for rasters and original glyph vector path is used. When you create a print style sheet it is smart to consider scenarios and printer capabilities. Inkjet printers dither the text. Mixing colours. They have more 'ticks' to get the right appearance.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
  @media print {
      h1 {
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        text-shadow: 0 0 0 #ccc;
      }

      @media print and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
        h1 {
          color: #ccc;
          -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: It works! You're a genius! [Here's a demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/hDZBt/show/) Tested in IE11, Chrome & Firefox.

Comment: make sure you don't try to use "transparent" instead of "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)" as it will not work with IE.

Comment: Works for me today in Chrome, but not in FF.

Answer (score 6):

I found had to :

1. Add `!important` to the css rule... ***and...***
2. In the Firefox print dialog, tick the option for "Appearance: Print background colors"

I couldn't get it to work in Chrome.

Comment: Sorry, not quite accurate. Option 2 works even if Option 1 is not performed.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey, that's not what I'm seeing in FireFox v24 on OSX for this page: http://www.awesometimer.com/results/nightingale_nightmare/ if I remove the "!important" rule the trophies are all printed black (the trophies are simply characters in fontawesome).

Comment: In my Firefox, if you go to File->Page Setup, and check the box "Print Background Colors & Images", then your trophies print gray. I'm using Firefox 24 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

I thought that is the only div on that page. Make the following change, it should work fine.

```
<style>
@media print {
div.red {
      color: #cccccc !important;
  }
</style>
```

And change the html of the div tag like below

Answer (score 3):

Some browsers add more respect to your gray if you add color: Replace `#777` with `#778`. Be wary of opacity. Sometimes, even if the print preview will show great results, it only actually works on select printers. Printers with unlucky firmware will fail to print your text at all if it is gray using opacity.

Comment: For those who come after me; I am in a situation where this opacity fallback is perfect for me.   I want something to show only if its color is unchanged, so I change that which can be hidden or greyed with opacity.  :)

Answer (score 3):

You just need to output your grey font in svg. Browsers don't change color in svg. Here's an example:

```
<svg height="40" width="200">
   <text font-size="28px" y="25" x="30" fill="#ffffff" >
   Some text
   </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that **TEXT color is not inherited by "general purpose" stylesheet**, but must be forced again in print css file.

In other words, even if text color is set in the general css file (one with `media='all'` attribute), it is ignored when printed, at least in Firefox and Chrome.

I found that writing again (redundant but..... necessary) text color in print css file (one with `media='print'` attribute), color now will be considered.

Comment: I wonder why I couldn't get that to work. An example page would be interesting to look at.

Answer (score 1):

This solution working in all browsers:

`.text{
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 2px 0 #red;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Give importance to color:

```
.bgcol{
background-color:skyblue !important;
}
 .subject_content,h2,p{
 color:rgba(255, 255, 255) !important;
    margin: 25px auto;

}
<body class="bgcol">
       <div class="subject_content">
      <h2 class='text-center'>fhddfhnt area</h2>
      <p>sdgdfghdfhdfh.</p>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing above was working for me so I finally figured it out.

Always give colors to direct elements. Ex. Suppose your html is

```
<div class='div'><br/>
      < h1>Text< /h1><br/>
</div>
```

and your CSS

```
.div { 
     color: #ccc; 
    }
```

This was my case. In this case no matter what you do the color won't show.

You have to do

```
.div h1 { 
 color: #ccc; 
}

@media print { 
 .div h1 { 
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
   } 
}
```

Hope this helps you!!

Please reply if you find a better solution as this is what I could find after 2 hrs and it works for me.