# colour of the glyphicon icon is not changing in print preview

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I changed the colour of the glyphicon icon to be blue. To change the colour I have used the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
          .colorful {
                color: blue !important;
            }
            @media print {
              .colorful {
                color: blue !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment colorful" style="padding-left:100px;padding-top:100px"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

In screen it is showing as blue colour
[image]

But in print preview the icon is displayed as black colour
[image]

I am using chrome browser. I need to make the icon appear in blue colour in print preview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615681/grey-font-color-printing

Comment: It may help to you

Comment: Thank you for your help. But text colour is getting changed, only the glyphyicon icon color is not changing in print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After inspecting your icon, it becomes apparent that you need to have `:before` as the selector for your icon so that you can properly apply the color in print. See screenshot below:

[image]

That said, you need to modify your CSS accordingly. Run the snippet below, then press `Ctrl+P`.  You'll notice that your icon is now blue in print preview.

```css
          .colorful {
                color: blue !important;
            font-size:41px;
            }
            @media print {
              .colorful:before {
                color: blue !important;
            }
        }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment colorful" style="padding-left:100px;padding-top:100px"></span>
```