# Is it possible to use CSS to have distinct styling for greyscale printers and color printers?

Tags: html, css, printing

Using media print, and modern versions of HTML/CSS, is it possible with or without JavaScript to auto-select a different stylesheet for greyscale, B&W and color printers?

The idea is that we use syntax highlighting and on the omnipresent greyscale laserprinters the rendered greyscales of the colors make the text less legible.

Comment: could you post and image of the greyscale text compared to B&W and color - so far only possible solutions I've seen are to do with the actual styling - see [post 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615681/grey-font-color-printing) and [post 2](https://css-tricks.com/dont-rely-on-background-colors-printing/)

Comment: @DexDave, this is a question for some W3C standards (in particular, the [in-progress working draft of XSLT](https://www.w3.org/XML/Group/qtspecs/specifications/xslt-30/html/Overview.html)). It is a matter of accessibility and we are investigating whether it is at all possible, or whether we would simply create drop-down to select the print style. I don't have an image, but we do have styling (unpublished yet) for B&W.

Comment: I thought this wasn't possible, but looking at this [short summary](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp), there seems to be something I can do with choosing the bit depth or color capabilities.

Comment: Well in that case then I haven't come across a work around for this - please here if you find one - good luck

Comment: yes you might be able to achieve that with color capabilities - sounds promising looking at that spec